# How to increase performance of tile caches if vendor parameter filters are needed?

Tags: geoserver, wms, performance, cache

My application uses vendor parameters to filter the data. It takes some time to generate all tiles on the server. Therefor I'm trying to increase the performance of the application.

I'm using geoserver as my tileserver. I looked up if [caching](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/using.html#geowebcache-integration-with-geoserver-wms) would be a solution, but it does not support vendor parameters. The only solution I could think of when trying to cache tiles is to filter it on the client, by having a separate layer for each possibility. However this does not seem very doable.

I welcome any suggestions on how to improve performace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GeoCache is not the only caching software (even if it fits nicely in the Geoserver ecosystem and UI).

You could try [MapCache](http://mapserver.org/mapcache/) (from the fine MapServer folks) which states to support vendor params (see last item on feature list). I could not find documentation on the matter, but the author(s) will usually answer quickly to well-termed questions.

If MapCache fails then you might try a general HTTP cache (ie not specialized for OGC services) like apache [mod_cache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html) which, after a long incubation, is now ready for production use. You are probably going to front geoserver with apache anyway.

I would suggest you start with **mod_cache** first because of easier setup.